# How to substract the count from dafaframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
index = (df[df['Index_name'] == ''])['float'].value_counts()
index['Index_con'].sum()

irs = irs_df.dropna()    
irs.reset_index(drop=True)
len(irs_df_p.index)
```

I want to substract the count of `index['Index_con'].sum()` from `len(irs_df_p.index)`. How this can be done ?

Comment: please show a sample of your input and expected output

Comment: 'index' and 'irs' are data frames. I want  to substract the count of one dataframe from another dataframe

Comment: Can you be explicit of what you mean by "substract from another dataframe"? Do you mean substract from a column of the dataframe? Or remove the rows?

Comment: I mean if one df has 100 records and another has 80 records. Then i want 100-80 = 20. based on above workings , please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign those values to variables to subtract them

```
df_sum = index['Index_con'].sum()
length = len(irs_df_p.index)
print(length - df_sum)
```